# Exception caught during execution of merge command

Tags: git-pull

When I did pull netbeans output showed me this one:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: 
Exception caught during execution of merge command. 
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Not a DIRC file.
```

I am not familiar with this error: how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

`DIRC` references "dir cache" (as [seen here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301287)).

Since Netbeans uses [jgit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), try and clone the repository again in a new folder, then check if the pull still triggers the same error.
Maybe your current local repository is somehow corrupted.